# How To Add One UIGestureRecognizer to All UITextView without blocking textView touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

How To Add One `UIGestureRecognizer` to All `UITextView` without blocking textView touches..

i want to call a method when any one touch any UITextView. pls any one give me ans.

Comment: what's your actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first u must add `uitextfield` delegate

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

then use that method

```
(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *) textField
```

Comment: thenx bro that method is use full.

Answer (score 3):

`<UITextFieldDelegate> 
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `UITextFieldDelegate` methods or add a `UIView` under the `UITextField` and add **gesture recognizer** to `UIView`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
}
```

Then you Handle following method in above action

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

Your total solution is Like this this way:

```
     #import "YourTextView.h" 

        @implementation YourTextView

        - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

 NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
        }
    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
        NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
    }
```

I hope this is helpful for you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

use this code this is delegate

```
<UITextFieldDelegate> 
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```